# If $A \cap B = \{0\}$ then $A^\perp + B^\perp = V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

Is this statement true: If $A \cap B = \{0\}$ then $A^\perp + B^\perp = V$.

I am trying to prove a bigger question, and my post with the full problem statement is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401476/if-range-a-cap-range-b-0-and-ba-0-then-rank-a-rank-b-ra). But my proof for that other question comes down to the above statement. If the above is true, then I am done. If the above is false, then back to the drawing board. The above statement seems true, but I'm having trouble proving it. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I am sorry but can I ask what is plus sign meaning? Do you mean the spanning space of $A^\perp$ and $B^\perp$? Also, are $A$ and $B$ vector spaces?

Comment: If that is the case, take the sketch of the proof: use contradiction: suppose $v\ne 0\in V\backslash (A^\perp+B^\perp)$, We find a orthogonal basis of $V$ containing an orthogonal basis of $A^\perp+B^\perp$ and by Gram-Schmidt we can "delete the components in $A^\perp+B^\perp$". So after deleting, $v\in(A^\perp+B^\perp)^\perp$, which means $v\in A\cap B$, or $v=0$, contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

As we know $(X+Y)^\perp\leq X^\perp\cap Y^\perp$.
Therefore
$$
(A^\perp+B^\perp)^\perp\leq A^{\perp\perp}\cap B^{\perp\perp}=A\cap B=0\ \Rightarrow\ 
(A^\perp+B^\perp)^\perp=0.
$$
It follows that $V=A^\perp+B^\perp$.

Comment: You assumed that $A$ and $B$ are subspaces

Comment: @ManuelOcaña Your counterexample is good; thank you for your contribution. And just to confirm: If A and B are subspaces, then the original claim is true?

Comment: Yes, because if $U$ is a subspace of $V$, then $(U^{\perp})^{\perp}=U$, and you can use the argument provided by @kabenyuk

Comment: @ManuelOcaña Yes, of course. Otherwise, what is the point of requiring $A\cap B=0$.

Answer (score 3):

No, Let $A$ be the nonegative y-axis and $B$ the nonpositive y-axis in $\bf{R}^2$. Then the complement is the x-axis for both and therefore the sum of their complements is the x-axis, not $\bf{R}^2$. If you assume $A$ and $B$ to be subspaces then yes, as a commenter has pointed out.